# Copy files including directory structure only if their modification date has changed since

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a script which takes a source-path as input and copies all files that have been changed since a given date, including their directory structure:

```
param([string]$source,[string]$datum)
(Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $datum }) | Copy-Item -Destination C:\tmp -Recurse
```

It works. The problem is, that it copies the files, including their directory structure, BUT it also copies all files from the source directories to the base path of the destination folder.

Where is the error?

Comment: additionally it copies all subfolders as direct child to the base folder of the destination directory :/

Comment: We all are script fans here, but sometimes it's best to go with tools that natively do this, vs trying to do it from scratch, well, unless it's a learning effort.  Use Robocopy instead as this sort of thing is what it was designed for and it's built into the OS and you can use it directly or call it from your script. Performance-wise, robocopy is also just faster than Copy-Item.

Comment: @postanote: If i could use robocopy, i would! ;)

Comment: Why is robocopy not helpful in this case?

Comment: Faulander, understood. ;^}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an overly complicated solution. It has a lot of error handling with 5 retry attempts. You should be able to apply it toward your needs.

I would look at `Line 21` to add your `Where-Object` and test it.

> **Example Use:** Copy-Files -Source "C:\Path\" -Destination "C:\Path2\"

```
Function Retry-Command {
    $Script:Counter = $Script:Counter + 1
    Write-Host "Attempt #" $Script:Counter "out of 5"
    if ($Script:Counter -ge 5) {
        PAUSE
    }
    else {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 -Verbose
    }
}
Function Copy-Files ([string]$Source, [string]$Destination ) {
    [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Folder_Content = @()
    [string]$Folder_Name = Split-Path $Source -Leaf
    [string]$Folder_Path = ($Source -replace [regex]::Escape($Source), ($Destination + $Folder_Name + "\"))
    [int]$Script:Counter = 0
    while (($Folder_Content.Count -eq "0") -and ($Counter -ne 5)) {
        try {
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "------------------------------" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Write-Host "Getting Content of" $Folder_Name -ForegroundColor Yellow
            [System.Collections.ArrayList]$Folder_Content = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $Source -Recurse -Force -ErrorVariable Child_Error)
            if ((-Not $Child_Error) -and ($Folder_Content.Count -ne 0) ) {
                Write-Host "Finished Getting Content of" $Folder_Name -ForegroundColor Green
                [int]$Script:Counter = 0
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "Failed to get Content of" $Folder_Name -ForegroundColor Red
                Retry-Command
            }  
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Unexpected Error getting Content of" $Folder_Name -ForegroundColor Red
            Retry-Command
        }
    }        
    if (-Not $Folder_Content.Count -eq 0) {
        while ((Test-Path -Path $Folder_Path) -eq $false) {
            try {
                Write-Host ""
                Write-Host "Creating" $Folder_Name "Folder" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Folder_Path -Force -ErrorVariable Folder_Error
                if (-Not $Folder_Error) {
                    Write-Host "Finished Creating" $Folder_Name "Folder" -ForegroundColor Green
                    [int]$Script:Counter = 0
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "Failed to create" $Folder_Name "Folder" -ForegroundColor Red
                    Retry-Command
                }            
            }
            catch {
                Write-Host "Unexpected Error Creating" $Folder_Name "Folder" -ForegroundColor Red
                Retry-Command
            }        
        }
        foreach ($Index in $Folder_Content) {
            [string]$Software_File_Name = Split-Path $Index.FullName -Leaf
            [string]$Software_File_Path = ($Index.FullName -replace [regex]::Escape($Source), ($Destination + (Split-Path $Source -Leaf) + "\"))
            while ((Test-Path -Path $Software_File_Path) -eq $false) {
                try {
                    Write-Host ""
                    Write-Host "Copying" $Index.FullName -ForegroundColor Yellow
                    Copy-Item -Path $Index.FullName -Destination $Software_File_Path -Force -ErrorVariable File_Error
                    if (-Not $File_Error) {
                        Write-Host "Finished Copying" $Index.FullName -ForegroundColor Green
                        [int]$Script:Counter = 0
                    }
                    else {
                        Write-Host "Failed to Copy" $Index.FullName -ForegroundColor Red
                        Retry-Command
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Host "Unexpected Error Copying" $Index.FullName -ForegroundColor Red
                    Retry-Command
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost you should be using [`robocopy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) for something like this. It has switches that likely handle your query:

> /e    Copies subdirectories. Note that this option includes empty directories. For additional information, see Remarks.
>
> /maxage:   Specifies the maximum file age (to exclude files older than N days or date).
>
> /l Specifies that files are to be listed only (and not copied, deleted, or time stamped).

So knowing that I would start experimenting with `robocopy $source $destination /e /maxage:30 /l` which should show all files in the directory tree that were modified in the last 30 days. `/maxage` might not be the switch you are looking for but its a fair guess.

---

The issue with your current logic is likely that `Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse` will be returning folders as well as files. So you could be passing a folder to `Copy-Item` which is where all the extra files are coming from. You should be able to mitigate that with the `-File` switch.

```
Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -File
```

Comment: unfortunatelly this doesn't retain the directory structure.

Comment: @Faulander what directory structure are you trying to keep? The entire directory structure regardless of the files being copied? That would be trivial in two copies. One that only does the directories and the other that does the files. It has not been clear to me what the outcome was supposed to look like.